# What is this automotive connector used on an Isuzu number plate light?

Tags: identification, connector

The connector on my Isuzu has failed. This is a waterproof connector, 2 pin, used on the number/license plate light.

[image: Isuzu Trooper number plate light]

Comment: Go to a breakers and find one (most likely, and probably quickest), or go to Isuzu and order one (least likely, several weeks...)

Comment: When people ask about automotive connectors I have two answers: 1) Ask the parts department at the dealer for that brand; 2) Ask https://connectorexperts.com/

Comment: the part number may be on the connector ... look closely

Comment: @DavideAndrea connectorexperts.com immediately identified the connector just off the front page ! Would you post your answer as a full stackexchange answer rather than a comment, so that I can accept it and then it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people ask about automotive connectors I have two answers:

1. Ask the parts department at the dealer for that brand
2. Ask connectorexperts.com

I am glad to see that the second solution worked for you.

Connector Experts P/N CE2055BF

https://connectorexperts.com/i-31644403-ce2055bf.html?ref=category:1261628

[image]